# Why ListView is always building the first three elements?

Tags: android, listview

I'm using ListView with:

```
private class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(parent == null)
            return null;

        Log.d(TAG, "getView: " + position);
        ...
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing in logcat is this pattern:

0,1,2,3,0,1,2,4,0,1,2,5...

Is there an explanation for this behavior? I'm working with large graphics and every getView call is expensive. Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: if(parent == null)
            return null; what s the use of this code

Comment: Are you using `wrap_content` as the ListView's height or even width?

Comment: Yes, <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... >

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was the reason behind this. After some optimalisations in getView body, the whole thing started to work in the more reasonable fashion - loading one consequential view at the time.